# Executing JS async functions in a synchronous manner (special case)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am trying out JS and wrapping my head around its `async` model. There is a project I am building for practice. It is a simple audio calling app using webRTC.

A scenario I am having trouble understanding is given below:

---

**User A** can mute their mic via calling `mute_mic()`. This function is as follows:

```
async function mute_mic(e) {

    let credential_payload = await retrieveOwnCred();// sensitive data, get from server, don't trust client

    // do other mic muting stuff

}
```

**User B** is the host of the call. So they can remove **User A's** mic. To do that, the host sends a signal to **User B**. **User B's** client then executes the following:

```
async function leave_mic() {

    stopped = await stopPublishingStream(streamID);  
    // some other clean up

}
```

---

At times this happens: **User A** is muting their mic, while the host has simultaneously asked to take their mic away. I can see unpredictable stuff happening. Maybe it is because the execution of the two `async` functions gets mixed up?

If that is the case, what is the best pattern to handle a situation like this? Can an industry expert provide an illustrative example?

I would want these functions to run synchronously, one after another. But I also need them to be `async`, since there is an `await` call within them. What tactics can I employ here?

Comment: Are you sure you have host/UserA/userB correct in your description?   "user B is host, can mute user A, so the host sends a signal to B" doesn't sound right - if B is the host, then they already have the signal.

Comment: *"Maybe it is because the execution of the two async functions gets mixed up?"* - Are you asking us that or telling us that?  The code shown has no obvious problems, and the only description of the issue so far is "unpredictable stuff [is] happening", so we can't really say what specifically is failing.  But we can assure you that when you `await` an `async` operation, the following code is not executed until that operation completes.  (Until the `Promise` resolves.)  Can you be more specific about the problem or provide a more concrete example demonstrating it?

Comment: `await mute_mic; await leave_mic` will essentially run in a synchronous order.

Comment: you are mixing local actions (mute mic, triggered from a button click) with remote actions (moderator takes mic away). This is somewhat similar to https://jsfiddle.net/fippo/vd2gq3sn/2/ -- the second click event doesn't wait for the first one to be finished

Comment: @PhilippHancke yes I realize that is the case

Comment: Sounds like a non-problem since nothing "unpredictable" happens if two near-random event handlers try to mute at the same time. Microphone mute is idempotent. A more interesting case might be the host muting and the user unmuting at nearly the same time, but that's an app logic question.

Answer (score 2):

the nub of your question, to me, seems to be:

> Maybe it is because the execution of the two async functions gets
> mixed up?

This shouldn't be happening. You can easily chain these two functions by simply doing:

```
await mute_mic(); 
await leave_mic();
```

In the above `leave_mic()` **will always run** after `mute_mic()`.

the only reason I can see that these wouldn't run in the correct order would be if you did something like:

```
mute_mic(); 
leave_mic();
```

---

These functions are still asynchronous, the `await` just retains the ordering. This is because `async`/`await` is simply syntactical sugar for a promise, so you could also think of/write the above as:

```
mute_mic()
.then(() => {
   leave_mic();
});
```

See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) for more information on this.

---

> how do I call it when attaching it to the onclick state of a button

I'd just declare a new function:

```
function async click_handler() {
   await mute_mic(); 
   await leave_mic();
}

mute_mic_btn.onclick = click_handler;
```

Again, remember this is **still async** you can't return something from this directly. The async/await is just flattering the structure for you. If your new to JS [get to grips with promises.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Fair enough, but how do I call it when attaching it to the onclick state of a button, i.e. `mute_mic_btn.onclick = mute_mic;`. I cannot include `await` there right.

Comment: Moreover, for completeness,could you add a small explanation in lay terms about how calling `await func` is fundamentally different from `func` - given `func` is `async` in both cases.

Comment: `func` **is not async**, `async func` is async. @HassanBaig Functions are not async by nature, they become async when you add the async keyword. Like I've already explained, `async` is just a code short cut for promises. I'd suggest you [read and understand these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the other links I've already added in this answer

Comment: [Specifically this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)